# Given a link $L\subset S^3$ how to construct a link $L'$ whose complement have hyperbolic structure?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

*Thurston* claimed that almost all closed 3-manifolds are hyperbolic. To support this, he said that every closed 3-manifold is obtained by Dehn surgery along some link whose complement is hyperbolic. And he proved that most surgeries along this link have hyperbolic structure.

The [*Lickorish–Wallace* theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lickorish%E2%80%93Wallace_theorem) tells us that every closed orientable 3 manifold can be described via integral Dehn surgery along a link in $S^3$. So my ***Question*** is, given a link $L\subset S^3$, how to construct (modify) a link $L'$ whose complement is hyperbolic? Because we know that $\infty$-sugery along any knot does not change the manifold. Thus we can hope to prove Thurston's claim.

We know that if a knot $K\subset S^3$ is not satellite or torus, then it is hyperbolic. So let's say, if we start with a sattelite knot, then we can add an unknot  which intersect the indecomposable torus non-trivially. Then in this process we can kill off the indecomposable torus. But I am unable to prove that in this process we have not constructed any new indecomposable torus. Also I don't know whether this complememnt is Seifert or hyperbolic.

***EDIT:*** *(Question 2)* Can we construct $L'$ from $L$ by adding only trivial knots?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would be a better question if you said how L' and L are intended to be related.

Comment: @DannyRuberman I have edited my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[Prime augmented alternating links](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=903861) are hyperbolic. These are obtained from an alternating link by adding little loops about each *twist region* (so in the figure, each crossing).

[image: Augmented alternating link]

Any link with a prime projection can be obtained by Dehn filling on an augmented alternating link ($\pm 1$ surgery along crossing loops changes the crossing). So this gives an elementary way of embedding $L\subset L'$ where $L$ is a link and $L'-L$ is an unlink, and $L'$ has hyperbolic complement.

See also this [survey article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2796634) by Jessica Purcell.

Answer (score 7):

Robert Myers, in his [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-273-01/S0002-9947-1982-0664030-0/S0002-9947-1982-0664030-0.pdf) "Simple knots in compact, orientable 3-manifolds", proved that every compact, orientable three-manifold (without sphere boundary components) contains a hyperbolic knot.

It follows that every link $L$ in the three-sphere is a sublink of a hyperbolic link $L'$.  This answers your first question.  It is also possible to arrange that the components of $L' - L$ are unknots in $S^3$, but I do not have a reference at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite by adding trivial knots, but in a lot of situations it is possible to homotope a link to get a new link with hyperbolic complement.  See "Excellent 1-manifolds in compact 3-manifolds" (Myers).  Some of these results work for when there are additional boundary components too and allow some control over the extra boundary - see "Totally geodesic boundaries of knot complements" (Kent).